Interval not getting cleared in angular typescript
Interval is not getting cleared even after passing intervalId in the clearInterval() function. I want the interval (scheduler) to stop after some time. I have multiple intervals running. I want other intervals to stop. Only one interval should run at a time.Where am i doing wrong?
private interval1:any;
private interval2:any;
func1(){

     this.interval1=interval(10000).pipe(startWith(10000)).subscribe(() => {
            console.log("interval1");    
            this.clearAutoRefresh(this.interval2);
          });
}

func2(){

     this.interval2=interval(10000).pipe(startWith(10000)).subscribe(() => {
            console.log("interval2");    
            this.clearAutoRefresh(this.interval1);
          });
}
    
  clearAutoRefresh(intervalIdToClear:any): void {

    if (intervalIdToClear) {
      clearInterval(intervalIdToClear);
    }else{
      console.error("interval not found");
    }
  }


This issue would not have happened if you had proper typing. You are storing subscriptions. If you used type Subscription rather than any, TypeScript would have made you aware that something isn't right.

RxJs interval is not the same as setInterval. First one returns a subscription, while the latter returns an interval id.
For your code, you can try unsubscribing, the subscription returned and stored in interval1 or interval2.
  clearAutoRefresh(intervalIdToClear: Subscription): void {
    if (intervalIdToClear) {
      intervalIdToClear.unsubscribe();
    }else{
      console.error("interval not found");
    }
  }

